# What is HostProtectionAttribute and why do we use it?

Tags: c#, clr, msdn

I would like to learn more about the HostProtectionAttribute in C#. Certainly, I read the MSDN documentations [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403276.aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z608z9y8(v=vs.110).aspx) but I couldn't figure out why we use it. In the documentation there are terms like "host programming model" which made the topic even more confusing for me.

Suppose that we have a method that has this attribute and what happens if I delete it?

Answer (score 2):

As the documentation spells out below;

> Given these attributes, SQL Server specifies a **list of HPAs** that are
>   **disallowed in the hosted environment** through **code access security
>   (CAS)**. The CAS requirements are **specified by one of three SQL Server
>   permission sets: SAFE, EXTERNAL_ACCESS, or UNSAFE**. One of these three
>   security levels is specified when the assembly is registered on the
>   server, using the CREATE ASSEMBLY statement. Code executing within the
>   **SAFE or EXTERNAL_ACCESS permission sets** must avoid certain **types or
>   members** that have the
>   **System.Security.Permissions.HostProtectionAttribute** attribute applied.
>
> **The HostProtectionAttribute is** not a security permission as much **, in that **it identifies specific code
>   constructs**, either **types** or **methods**, that the **host may disallow**

```
I couldn't figure out why we use it.
```

We use it to help us write predictable code in the host environment because

> **it identifies specific code constructs, either types or methods, that the host may disallow**

```
Suppose that we have a method that has this attribute and what happens if I delete it?
```

When you delete it, in case the method contains types or certain code constructs that maybe disallowed by the host, you will never know and as a result it may result in unpredictable behavior of your code in the host environment such as SQL server. I hope that makes it more helpful.